# WaitAll with Task not working

Tags: c#

I Created several Task in the way below. But it seems `WaitAll` is not working. It is sending response without wait. Anything goes wrong here?

```
private void GetItemsPrice(IEnumerable<Item> items, int customerNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            for (var i = 0; i < items.Count(); i += 50)
            {
                var newTask = DoGetItemsPrice(items.Skip(i).Take(50), customerNumber);    
                tasks.Add(newTask);
            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLog.WriteLog(GetType().Name, "GetItemsPrice", string.Format("customerNumber={0}", customerNumber), ex.Message);
        }
    }

private static Task DoGetItemsPrice(IEnumerable<Item> items, int customerNumber)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var sxApiObj = new SxApiService();
            var request = new OEPricingMultipleRequest();

            request.customerNumber = customerNumber;
            request.arrayProduct =
                items.Select(
                    itemCode =>
                    new OEPricingMultipleinputProduct
                    {
                        productCode = itemCode.ItmNum,
                        quantity = itemCode.Quantity,
                        warehouse = ConfigurationVariables.DefaultWareHouse
                    }).ToArray();
            var response = sxApiObj.OEPricingMultiple(ConfigurationVariables.SfAppServer,
                                                  ConfigurationVariables.SfUserId,
                                                  ConfigurationVariables.SfPassword,
                                                  request);

            if (response.arrayPrice != null)
            {
                foreach (var priceData in response.arrayPrice)
                {
                    var productCode = priceData.productCode;
                    var item = items.FirstOrDefault(itm => itm.ItmNum == productCode);

                    if (item == null) continue;
                    item.ItmListPrice1 = priceData.price.ToString("c", ConfigurationVariables.UsCulture);
                    item.ItmListPrice2 = priceData.discountAmount.ToString("c", ConfigurationVariables.UsCulture);
                    item.ItmListPrice3 = priceData.extendedAmount.ToString("c", ConfigurationVariables.UsCulture);

                    item.Quantity = priceData.netAvailable;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: By calling TaskFactor.StartNew() you immediately start the task. In DoGetItemsPrice() you're making a service call and getting a response... What do you expect to happen here?

Comment: i am not sure `WaitAll` is getting executed

Comment: Have you debugged and set a breakpoint on WaitAll to make sure it's hit? It's possible that your tasks are simply finishing before any noticeable wait occurs. Also, make sure your exception handler isn't being hit.

Comment: Do i need to handle `AggregateException` and if so how to add that?

Comment: No, you're catching all Exceptions, of which AggregateException is a sub-class. Is anything written to your ErrorLog?

Comment: nothing is written. I debugged and it seems and `waitall` is working as it takes some time there.

Comment: Sounds like there's nothing wrong with your 'WaitAll' call then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with my question. `WaitAll` works fine and the code also correct.